# Why this method that execute this simple query give me a wrong result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have the following problem.

I have this Microsoft SQL Server query:

```
Select AVG(Severity) AS 'Average Severity' from VulnerabilityAlertDocument
```

that, executed into Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio, return to me this float: 7,34792844929602

Now I am trying to create a C# method that simply implement this query and return the obtained value, so I have done something like this:

```
    public double getVulnerabilitySeverityAverage()
    {
        double vulnerabilitySeverityAverage;

        _strSQL = "Select AVG(Severity) AS 'Average Severity' from VulnerabilityAlertDocument";

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = _strSQL;

        vulnerabilitySeverityAverage = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return vulnerabilitySeverityAverage;
    }
```

The problem is that when the previous methos is executed the result value into **vulnerabilitySeverityAverage** is not the expected value (7,34792844929602) but it is the wrong value: **-1.0**

Why? What is it wrong? What am I missing?

Tnx

Answer (score 9):

From [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**.

Since your query is `SELECT` statement, so..

As a solution, you might need to use [`ExecuteScalar` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns the first column of the first row in the result as an `object`.

```
vulnerabilitySeverityAverage = (double)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: If only people would actually **look** at the excellent, freely available documentation!

Comment: @marc_s Amen.. Sometimes I really hesitate should I add this information as a comment or as an answer. Because solution can be found in 30 seconds to look at their documentations. This feels bad to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `command.ExecuteScalar()` Method